# How does one flush the non-database cache (such as memcache) from CiviCRM code?

Tags: cache

I've seen from a [different question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-are-the-different-caching-mechanisms-relevant-when-developing/96#96) a suggestion to use `CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches()` as the "granddaddy" of all cache flushing. However, I'd like to know if this is only clearing the cache in the database, such as `civicrm_cache` and so on or if it also clears non-database cache as well such as memcache.

As far as I can tell the above function calls `CRM_Core_Config::cleanupCaches()` which calls `CRM_Core_Config::clearDBCache()` and that function truncates various cache tables. Am I missing something? How do the other caching backends get flushed?

Comment: I found this under api/v3/Job.php: `if ( $dbCache ) {
    CRM_Core_Config::clearDBCache( );
  } if ( $memCache ) {
    CRM_Utils_System::flushCache( );
  }` which seems to confirm my suspicion that there are two ways to clear the cache depending on what backend caching method is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the function `CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches` does *not* flush the memory caches, even though it will rebuild the database cache, menus and sessions. In order to also flush the memory caches you need to also call: `CRM_Utils_System::flushCache( );` (This was confirmed by Lobo but I think it needed to be written more explicitly as an *answer* and not as how things *should* be.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the function CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches should also flush the memory caches, and hence call: CRM_Utils_System::flushCache( );

This will make things more consistent and actually rebuild all caches as the function name suggests

Comment: Can you edit and clarify your answer Lobo? Are you saying currently CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches does not flush the memory caches? So if I want to clear the memory caches I need to call CRM_Utils_System::flushCache()? And should I create an issue to patch core?

Comment: yes, i would create an issue and submit a PR to add the changes to the rebuild function