# Is the container cache not cleared as part of `drush cc all`?

Tags: core

I like being able to use the DI container in my extensions via the container hook, however I've run into the same problem a few times when switching branches that I get this error:

> You have requested a non-existent service "myserviceid"

After trying `drush cc all` I'd expect the container cache to be clearer, but it doesn't seem to be. My go-to option is to remove all files in the `sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/` directory, but this seems like it should be handled by the cache clear command.

I'm aware there's an option to not use a container cache, but my question is whether the failure to clear the container cache is expected, or should it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the caches by running `drush cc civicrm`, by removing everything inside the templates_c directory, and by running clear caches in CiviCRM > Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and File Paths.

In my experience, it's beneficial to run `drush cc civicrm` separately from `drush cc all`, which seems to clear only Drush and Drupal caches.

There is a bug reported about `drush cc all` not clearing CiviCRM caches:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19206

Comment: I would expect `all` to include the CiviCRM cache, does it not? I remove files from `templates_c` manually and that works. I'm just confused by what is required to clear the container cache using drush, my expectation is that `drush cc all` should do it, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I think the issue is that it seems that you built something custom so you would need to add it to the drush script. I could be wrong, and if so, others will pipe in. Did you try `drush cc civicrm`?

Comment: `drush cc civicrm` also seems to fix it. Does this mean that the civicrm cache is not cleared as part of `drush cc all`, even though it is listed when you just do `drush cc`?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: It seems like a bug that the civicrm cache is not fully cleared as part of `drush cc all`, especially since `civicrm` is listed as one of the cache options if you just do `drush cc`. I'll mark this as accepted, thanks.

Comment: Yes, my answer noted that there is a bug report filed on this issue. I'm glad the work around helped. :)